# Can tc or nftables change the SA/TA in 802.11 frame?

Tags: wifi, nftables, tc, netfilter

I am looking for a way to change the SA/TA on a Wi-Fi frame. I need this because I have a VM (running with QEMU and vmnet-bridged) in a MacBook that connects to a Wi-Fi interface, and a laptop connected via patch cable to the same router that the MacBook is connected to via Wi-Fi. In this [question](https://superuser.com/q/1819986/1269341), I realized what is preventing the VM from getting the packet is the TA/SA in the frame:

[image: 1]

The MAC address of the VM is `52:54:00:12:34:80`. This packet is captured in the router (OpenWRT). As you can see, SA/TA has the MAC address of the VM, and I want to change it, possibly with `tc` or nftables. But I think nftables can't do it, and I'm considering `tc`, but I don't know what offsets I need to define to change the SA/TA in a Wi-Fi frame, unless of course `tc` can do it.

Actually, I want to change the MAC address of the VM to the MAC address of the router, and I hope this helps. In other words, I want to do L2 (MAC) NAT on the router.

If `tc` or perhaps nftables can do it, could you please write how I can change the SA/TA using these utilities.